# ionic 3 cli 'ionic cordova run android' command throws an error

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I updated the cli to ionic 3 version and when i run

> ionic cordova run android

to build apk file and run in android emulator I got this error

```
    C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\beep>ionic cordova run android
Running app-scripts build: --address 0.0.0.0 --port 8100 --p 8100 --livereload-port 35729 --r 35729 --iscordovaserve --externalIpRequired --nobrowser

[20:52:20]  build dev started ...
[20:52:20]  clean started ...
[20:52:20]  clean finished in 11 ms
[20:52:20]  copy started ...
[20:52:20]  transpile started ...
[20:52:22]  transpile finished in 2.53 s
[20:52:22]  preprocess started ...
[20:52:22]  deeplinks started ...
[20:52:23]  deeplinks finished in 52 ms
[20:52:23]  preprocess finished in 54 ms
[20:52:23]  webpack started ...
[20:52:23]  copy finished in 2.77 s
[20:52:31]  webpack finished in 8.53 s
[20:52:31]  sass started ...
[20:52:32]  sass finished in 1.11 s
[20:52:32]  postprocess started ...
[20:52:32]  postprocess finished in 7 ms
[20:52:32]  lint started ...
[20:52:32]  build dev finished in 12.29 s
> cordova run android
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\java\jdk1.8.0_101
Error: Could not find an installed version of Gradle either in Android Studio,
or on your system to install the gradle wrapper. Please include gradle
in your path, or install Android Studio


[ERROR] Cordova encountered an error.
        You may get more insight by running the Cordova command above directly.

[ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova run android (exit code 1).
```

what I already tried to do and it not helps:
 1. removed android studio and install again.
 2. run these commands

```
cordova platform rm android
cordova platform add android
npm cache clear
```

3. update the sdk in android studio

nothing really helps to solve this issue.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I was facing the same issue please run the below command it should work fine.

ionic cordova run android --livereload

Answer (score 8):

For me this solved the problem:

```
ionic cordova platform rm android 
ionic cordova platform add android
```

Answer (score 2):

add the location of Android Studio's Gradle (e.g, `/usr/local/android-studio/gradle/gradle-3.2/bin` for linux) to your PATH environment variable

Answer (score 2):

that's how I solve this issue.

1. download gradle latest version bin file this link [link to download gradle](https://gradle.org/releases)
2. extract the winzip file into java folder (e.g C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\gradle-3.5)
3. go to my computer right click -> properties.
4. then go to advanced system setting in left side menu.
5. advances -> environment Variables then select Path.
6. add new environment variable called  **%GRADLE_HOME%/bin**

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same issue and now resolved the issue as below steps

1. Downloaded the gradle zip version and extracted to path `user\<username>\android-sdk\gradle`
2. the same path configured in environment variable both like `GRADLE_HOME` and `path`